# Using a dll file in matlab code

Tags: matlab, dll, shared-libraries, mex, loadlibrary

I need to use a function in Matlab that is defined by a dll file. I got an example that guy converted a dll to mexw32 file but i have known how I do this. I tried use *loadlibrary* but it didn't create any file.
How I can do this?

Comment: `loadlibrary` will load a dll into MATLAB, if you want to create a mexw32 file, you'll need to create a C-MEX function, is this what you want?

Comment: Yes....how can I create a C-MEX function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`loadlibrary`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/using-c-shared-library-functions-in-matlab-.html) is MATLAB's implementation of [FFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) services, a mechanism of calling functions in external shared libraries. It involves converting between C-types and their equivalent MATLAB data types to pass data around.

[MEX-files](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/c-c-source-mex-files.html) are also a kind of dynamically linked libraries (with `.mex*` extension), that can be run directly in MATLAB as a regular function without any special syntax.

The difference is that it has a specific gateway routine called [`mexFunction`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexfunction.html), which receives both input and output as `mxArray` type. [`mxArray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxarray.html) is an opaque type defined in `mex.h` header file, which is the fundamental type underlying all MATLAB data. You usually manipulate this data using functions in the [MEX library API](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/programming-interfaces-for-c-c-fortran-com.html).

Comment: @ACB: I have provided links to the relevant documentation of both cases (loadlibrary and MEX-functions). It is well explained there :)