# Define a new control statement in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm interested in defining a new control statement in MATLAB. Matlab already has loop definitions such as `for`, `parfor`, `if`, and `while` but I would like define a new control statement. Is this possible in MATLAB?

Comment: I don't think so. Which one would you want? I sometimes miss a `do`...`while`: run a statement at least once and _then_ check wether to repeat or nor

Comment: What I'm currently interested in doing is a loop similar to parfor where I can just submit all of loops to a queue for my local cluster.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You could of course write a normal function and supply a function handle and range for the parameter.

Comment: I think that this is impossible, it most likely would require a lot of support from the JIT compiler. However, you should try to define this as function instead. This is not really different from how this is normally done in any language. Just look at the `for_each` loop in c++ for example.

Comment: If you want to know how to submit MATLAB jobs to a cluster, you should better ask that. Your current question will certainly only have the answer: No. Would you even know any other programming language where you could define your own *control statements*?

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm currently interested in doing is a loop similar to parfor
>   where I can just submit all of loops to a queue for my local cluster.

I don't think you can easily extend/modify the syntax of Matlab. It's not that flexible and I have never seen it. Although I do not know that for sure, I recommend asking Mathworks for an ultimate answer (most probably no).

However why not programming in C / Java (or any other language that does implement the control statements you like) and then combining them with Matlab?

C and Java are especially easy to combine with Matlab, but everything else in a dll should work. And from the dll you can call Matlab code, so hybrid programming (mixing Matlab and something else) is possible.

See also:

- [How do I call java code from a Matlab program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069414/how-do-i-call-java-code-from-a-matlab-program)
- [Call C++ code from MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601988/call-c-code-from-matlab)
- [Using a dll file in matlab code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116947/using-a-dll-file-in-matlab-code)
- [Call MATLAB Functions from C and C++ Applications](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/calling-matlab-software-from-a-c-application.html)

Comment: I'm totally capable of writing code to submit jobs to my cluster without this sort of extension, I'm just curious if there was a more "interesting" way to do it.

Comment: @aplassard Maybe you should kind of show in another question how you do it currently and then ask what is the most efficient/easiest way to do the same in Matlab. I'm still not sure I understand what exactly you want to have.